# Do I have to initialize ALL member variables of a class?

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

Let's say I have this code snippet running.

```
class Song
  def initialize(name, artist, duration)
    @name = name
    @artist = artist
    @duration = duration
  end

  def to_s
    "Song: #{@name}--#{@artist} (#{@duration})"
  end
end

SongA = Song.new("Bicyclops", "Fleck", 260)
puts SongA.to_s
```

If I replace `SongA = Song.new("Bicyclops", "Fleck", 260)` with `SongA = Song.new("Bicyclops", "Fleck")`, I get an error. Is this normal according to Ruby code construct?

Btw, I got the example from [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html). But I'm having trouble finding even after browsing through [this doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html). Thanks in advance for any resources you point me towards.

Comment: I think you should invest in a decent book on Ruby.

Comment: You may not want to use `SongA` as the variable name, as that implies it's a constant.

Comment: Do you mean method parameters or member variables?

Comment: @maerics: I believe is method parameters for the constructor.

Comment: In questions like this, it's a good idea to include the error message you get. Also, in the Ruby community, the term is usually "instance variable", not "member variable".

Comment: The book you're looking was written for Ruby 1.6. Ruby 1.6 and "Programming Ruby" is literally older than Internet Explorer 6! Ruby 1.6 was [September 2000](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/), "Programming Ruby" was also published in 2000, and IE 6 was [August 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function definition does not specify a default value for the input parameters, you must supply them.

```
  # Default artist is Nobody
  # Default duration is nil
  def initialize(name, artist='Nobody', duration=nil)
    @name = name
    @artist = artist
    @duration = duration
  end
```

You could then initialize it omitting the properties for which you defined default values.

```
# Using lowercase songA instead of SongA since 
# ruby will treat the uppercase SongA as a constant...
songA = Song.new('Bicyclops')
```

And you don't need to initialize all the class properties in the `initialize()` either. They can be added and initialized in other methods

```
def other_method
  @other_prop = "Another property"
end
```